# Same output for hashCode() and identityHashCode()

Tags: java, hashcode

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        System.out.println(obj.hashCode());
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(obj));
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
328332828
328332828
```

Then what is the use of using `hashCode()` and `identityHashCode()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaDoc of [identityHashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) Says:

*Returns an integer hash code for the parameter. The hash code returned is the same one that would be returned by the method java.lang.Object.hashCode(), whether or not the object's class has overridden hashCode(). The hash code for null is 0.*

To put it simply:

If you have overridden `hashCode()` method in your class, then calling `identityHashCode()` will invoke default `hashCode()` method, not your overridden method.

Answer (score 1):

- **hashCode** is overrideable
- **identityHashCode** is default (not overrided)    function